# Extracting a text file from tar with tarfile module in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, stream, extract

Is there a simple way to extract a text file from a `tar` file as a file object of text I/O in python 3.4 or later?

I am revising my python2 code to python3, and I found `TarFile.extractfile`, which used to return a file object with text I/O, now returns a `io.BufferedReader` object which seems to have binary I/O. The other part of my code expects a text I/O, and I need to absorb this change in some way.

One method I can think of is to use `TarFile.extract` and write the file to a directory, and open it by `open` function, but I wonder if there is a way to get the text I/O stream directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `io.TextIOWrapper` to wrap the `io.BufferedReader`.

Answer (score 0):

*you can use getmembers()*

```
import  tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("test.tar")
tar.getmembers()
```

*After that, you can use extractfile() to extract the members as file object. Just an example*

```
import tarfile,os
import sys
os.chdir("/tmp/foo")
tar = tarfile.open("test.tar")
for member in tar.getmembers():
    f=tar.extractfile(member)
    content=f.read()
    // do operations with your content
    sys.exit()
tar.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. `content` is binary. My question is how to get a text I/O.